# Web2Py minimal User authentication (username only)

Tags: python, database, authentication, web2py

I did not find anything on the web and so I'm asking here.

Is there a way to create a custom auth wich only requires a username? That means to login to a specific subpage one has only to enter a username, no email and no password etc.?

Or is there a better way to do this? E.g. a subpage can only be accessed if the username (or similar) exists in a db table?

Comment: I presume you have an initial authorization? Are you not able to restrict access to your subpages by groups? In essence, add users to a group within the database and then restrict access to your subpages by group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do something like this:

(in models file, or at the top of the controller(s), or even better make a function decorator)

Check `session.logged_in_user` to see if it's None, if None, redirect to /default/login where you present the user with a form:

```
form = FORM(Field('username'), requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.users.username))
```

On form submission (see web2py manual for form processing), if valid (e.g. if username exists in db.users table), set `session.logged_in_user = request.vars.username`

Here's a completish example (untested):

**models/Auth.py**

```
# Could also check whether session.logged_in_user exists in DB, but probably not needed
# If so though, should be renamed zAuth or something to come after db.py file
if not session or not session.logged_in_user:
  redirect(URL('default','login', vars={'next':request.vars.url}))
```

**controllers/default.py**

```
#in file: controllers/default.py
...
def login():
   form = FORM(Field('username', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.users.username))

   if form.process().accepted:
     session.logged_in_user = form.vars.username
     redirect(request.vars.next)
   elif form.errors:
     session.logged_in_user = None # not necessary, but oh well
     response.flash = "Please enter a valid username"

   return dict(form=form)
```

**views/default/login.html**

```
{{ extend 'layout.html' }}
{{ =form }}
```

By placing code in a models file, you can ensure it is executed on every page request.

This will not allow you to use web2py's authentication mechanism (i.e. `auth = AUTH()`), but I'm not sure that you'd want it for this anyway unless you're interested in using groups and permissions, etc. But if that's the case, adding passwords (even if it's a generic password or a blank one) seems like it wouldn't be too much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

web2py by default allows blank passwords. So simply hide the password fields in the login and registration forms using CSS. You should be able to use the default auth.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sign-in with only your unique username and password go to db.py and write this code:

```
auth.define_tables(username=True,signature=True)
db.auth_user.username.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'auth_user.username')
db.auth_user.email.readable = False
db.auth_user.email.writable = False
db.auth_user.first_name.readable = False
db.auth_user.first_name.writable = False
db.auth_user.last_name.readable = False
db.auth_user.last_name.writable = False
```

for me it worked